# Remove the Query String from a Url in HTML with a Regular Expression

Tags: html, regex, url, parsing

Given a html document, what is the most correct and concise regular expression pattern to remove the query strings from each url in the document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't usefully parse HTML with a regexp. If you know the format of the page in advance — eg.

- links are always in the form < a href="url with no unnecessary character escapes">, or
- all links are absolute, and no other non-link strings beginning with http: exist

then you can just about get away with it, but for general [X]HTML a regexp parser is unsuitable.

Depending on what language you're using, you'd need to find either an HTML parser library (eg. Python's BeautifulSoup), or an HTML tidier combined with a standard XML parser, then scan the document for < a> elements (and maybe others, eg. < img> if you're interested in those?), then split the attribute value on ‘?’.

Comment: Thank you bobince, I was actually using BeautifulSoup but was looking for a quick and dirty way rather than iterating through all the links.

Answer (score 2):

Re: Bobince's comment, the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) is a good html parser for .NET, its more forgiving with dealing with incorrect markup than other parsers.

Using this  will let you find all the A tags, then you can get the HREF and simply remove anything after and including a '?'

Answer (score 0):

Find this:

```
/href="([^\?"]*?)\?[^\"]*"/
```

Replace with:

```
href="\1"
```

you may have to watch out that it doesn't strip `<link>` tags.

Comment: There's quite a few cases that won't match:  href = "foo?bar", href = foo?bar (not valid but still could appear) href='foo?bar'